# Após mandar o código retornar um alert se os valores dos inputs estiverem zerados, ao apertar o botão a página trava

Tags: javascript

Quando os valores dos inputs estão zerados, o certo era aparecer um `alert` e uma mudança na `div`, porém a página trava e não consigo mais colocar números ou clicar no botão.

Percebi que quando tiro o `.lenght` o código funciona.

Por que o `lenght` trava a página?

```
function tabuada(){
let ini=document.getElementById('txt1')
let fim=document.getElementById('txt2')
let passo=document.getElementById('txt3')
let res=document.getElementById('res')

if (ini.value.lenght== 0 || fim.value.lenght== 0 || passo.value.lenght== 0){
    window.alert('[ERRO], dados faltando...')
    res.innerHTML='Impossível de contar...'
}
else{
    res.innerHTML='Contando:'
    let i=Number(ini.value)
    let f=Number(fim.value)
    let p=Number(passo.value)
if(i<f){
    //Contagem Crescente
    for(let c=i; c<=f; c += p){
        res.innerHTML+=`${c}\u{1F449}`
    }
        res.innerHTML+=`\u{1F3C1}`
}
else{
    //Contagem Regressiva
    for(let c=i; c>=f; c-=p){
        res.innerHTML+=`${c}\u{1F449}`
    }
        res.innerHTML+=`\u{1F3C1}`
}
}
}
```

Comment: O `lenght` está errado. O certo é `length`. Tente assim: `if (!+ini.value.trim() || !+fim.value.trim() || !+passo.value.trim()){`

Comment: Samzão presente !

Comment: @Sam Considerando que [uma string vazia é considerada `false`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-toboolean), nem precisava usar o `+` pra converter para número: `if (!ini.value.trim() || !fim.value.trim() || !passo.value.trim())`. Aliás, converter pra número pode dar problema, pois a string `"000"` é convertida para o número zero (ou seja, mesmo não sendo vazia, vai entrar no `if`).

Comment: A menos, é claro, que ele queira validar também que o valor é zero (que não ficou claro na pergunta). Enfim...

Comment: @hkotsubo É isso mesmo. Ele quer verificar se é vazio ou zero para disparar o alert.

Answer (score 0):

No `if` você utiliza `ini.value.length`. Isso não é possível para inputs, pois inputs não possuem `length`. Os elementos são os que você atribuiu nas variáveis nos `document.getElementByID`, que não podem ser usados dessa forma que você relatou na pergunta, NESTE CASO.

No seu caso, como você disse que está utilizando `inputs`, então você deve usar `value`.

Você citou que está querendo verificar se o campo está 'zerado'. Não entendi se você quer dizer se o campo possui 0 (zero) ou se o campo está vazio ("").

Vou fazer um exemplo com as duas opções para você observar.

- Se o seu caso for se o campo possuir 0 (zero):

```js
if (ini.value == 0 || fim.value == 0 || passo.value == 0) {
  //Sua condição aqui
}
```

- Agora se o seu caso for se o campo for vazio (""):

```js
if (ini.value == "" || fim.value == "" || passo.value == "") {
  //Sua condição aqui
}
```

Comment: É perfeitamente possível usar `ini.value.length`, pois o `value` é uma string e strings possuem `length`. O problema foi o erro de digitação, pois na pergunta foi usado `lenght` ("ht" em vez de "th"). E `input` não possui `length`, somente `minlength` e `maxlength`, [veja](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes).

Comment: Ok, corrigi a resposta. Obrigado, cara. Dei uma lida no seu link.